# Opening a new window using Javascript after a timeout caught by popup blocker

Tags: javascript, web, cross-browser, popup

I'm having a situation in which I want to allow the user to download a PDF. The generation of this PDF can take a couple of seconds, and I don't want a webserver thread to wait for the generation of the PDF, since that means the thread isn't available to handle other incoming requests.

So, what I would like to do is introduce the following URL patterns:

- `/request_download` which invokes a background job to generate the PDF;
- `/document.pdf` which will serve the PDF once it is generated

The use case is as follows.

A user clicks on 'Download PDF'. This invokes a piece of Javascript that'll show a spinner, make a request to `/request_download` and receive a HTTP 202 Accepted, indicating the request was accepted and a background job was created. The JS should then poll the `/request_download` url periodically until it gets HTTP 201 Created, indicating that the PDF has been created. A `Location` header is included that is used by the JS to forward the client to `/document.pdf`. **This has to be in a new window** (or tab, at least it shouldn't replace the current page). The level of expertise of our users is very low, so when I forward to the url, they might not know how to get back to the website.

**The problem**

Now, `window.open` works fine if it is invoked by the user via a click event. However, I want to invoke `window.open` in a callback function through `setInterval` as soon as I see that 201 Created response. However, browsers won't like that and will interpret it as a popup, causing it to get caught by popup blockers on IE8-10 as well as Chrome. Which makes sense.

I also can't open a new window and invoke the Javascript over there. In that case, users would see a blank page with a spinner. If that page then forwards to the `/document.pdf`, IE will show this yellow warning bar telling that it prevented files from being downloaded. Chrome and Firefox will do this without any problems, but a large percentage of our users is on IE.

**What I've tried, and didn't work**

- window.open(location)
- Setting the src of an iframe to the retrieve location
- Manually adding an `<a>` tag to the document body and trying to click it using javascript
- Adding an `<a>` tag to the document body and invoking a `MouseEvent` on it
- Partially works: opening a new window on user click and storing a reference to it, then perform the asynchronous requests and upon completion, set the location of the earlier opened window. But: IE will block this and say it prevented files from being downloaded. So still not a fully working solution.

I'm straight out of ideas on how I can make this work and decided and decided to ask The Internet for help. I'm hoping you guys can help me with this, or recognise the problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: tried  window.open(url , '_blank')?

Comment: @Sidharthan yeah, that also gets caught by the popup blocker on Chrome.

Comment: what call you are using to communicate between client and server??

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4098194/3090380

Comment: Great, thanks! That does work. I guess it's the only way to bypass the popup blocker.

Comment: Okay I cheered too early. IE's still behaving differently. When I set the location of the newly opened window, IE will still show that yellow warning bar telling me that it prevented files from being downloaded.. :-( Any thoughts?

Comment: I think as long as the window open happens in the event loop of a user interaction then you won't have problems with the pop up blocker. Perhaps you should show a link once the PDF is ready... What's less annoying for users?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I open a new window using a URL that is generated inside the getScript callback function, and avoid pop-up blockers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097255/how-can-i-open-a-new-window-using-a-url-that-is-generated-inside-the-getscript-c)